# recognizing custom packages in latexmkrc

Tags: packages, latexmk, document-configuration

I have a file, `jtc.sty`, that houses all the repetitive stuff that normally goes into a latex document (usepackage statments, turning paragraph indent off, and some formatting stuff) that I include in pretty much all of my tex files. However, I find it annoying to manually copy over that file every time I want to use it. Is there some way to configure `latexmkrc` so that it knows where to find `jtc.sty` whenever I use it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try searching this site? I'm pretty sure that this will answer your question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te

Comment: No worries! The longer you're around the site, the more familiar you become with which questions have already been asked. `:)` And does that question answer things for you? Is it okay if I vote to close this question as a duplicate of that one?

Comment: yes, that question answered mine. please vote to close this one if you like.

Comment: Sounds good. And welcome to the community! `:)`